# NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xml, image, byte

I am trying to read bytes of image from the XML file but I took that error at the second line.

```
XmlNodeList list = docc.GetElementsByTagName("Meaning");
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(list[index].Attributes["Meaning"].Value);
```

Comment: So what did you try? Where do you think this is coming from?

Comment: My project is a dictionary. I will show to user word's picture. I don't where comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before to set a value in

```
imageBytes
```

, verify

```
list
```

is not null, and

```
list[index].Attributes["Meaning"].Value
```

exist and is not null too!

You want to create BreakPoint in your code for debugging and to see your problem, and var content.

And please, for other question you ask, specify more details ( what is exact error, how you know error is in second line, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the `list[index]` has no attribute called `Meaning`. That would be the `"abc"` in:

```
<Meaning Meaning="abc">...</Meaning>
```

which sounds pretty unlikely. Also: check the xml namespace at that location.

Comment: So... this question has no `Meaning`? ;-)

Comment: I agree, especially since Meaning element is supposed to have a whole image. It is also recommended that you use the XmlNode.SelectNodes or XmlNode.SelectSingleNode method instead of the GetElementsByTagName method.